# quiz on webpage is taking whole page instead of a tiny bit

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where some information is on it + a quiz at the end. 
The problem is that the quiz is covering almost the whoel page. It has to be below the last paragraph.

Anyone can see what the problem might be ?

https://plnkr.co/edit/8re5W6mz73pnU40WaXP8?p=preview

This is a part of the code otherwise it would be too long ->

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 05% 00% 00% 05%;
}

.imageleft {
  float: left;
}

.paragraphs {
  margin: 5% 30% 2% 20%;
  width: 40%;
}

.right {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  margin: -11% 00% 00% 40%;
}

.imageright {
  width: 300px;
}

.quizbox {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 950px;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #00A7AE;
  margin-top: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #73B7DB;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <a class="imageleft circle" id="quiz">
      <font color="white">How</font>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    Geographische Informationssysteme werden in der Mobilitätsforschung eingesetzt, um <b>mehrere Perspektiven auf Verkehrssysteme und das Mobilitätsverhalten</b> miteinander in Beziehung zu setzen. Als gemeinsamer Nenner der verschiedenen Zugänge dient
    stets die räumliche Koordinate. Damit ist es möglich, in komplexen Fragestellungen mehrere Ansätze zu kombinieren und ganzheitliche Lösungen zu erzielen.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img class="imageright" src="http://ideaslab.sbg.ac.at/ideaslab/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/quiz300x200-300dpi.jpg" />
  </div>

</div>

<div class="quizbox">

  <!-- open main div -->
  <h1><span style="color:#00995D">Quiz</span></h1>
  <form id="form1" action=" ">
    <div class="row">
      <h3>Moths are a member of what order?</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" /> Octagon <span class="explanation" id="answer1" style="color:red"></span></div>

    <div class="row">
      <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" /> Leprosy <span class="explanation" id="answer2" style="color:red"></span></div>

    <div class="row">
      <input name="variable" type="radio" value="33" />Lepidoptera <span class="explanation" id="answer3" style="color:green"></span></div>
    &nbsp;
    <div class="row">
      <h3>Question 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input name="sub" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 1 <span class="explanation" id="answer4" style="color:green"></span></div>

    <div class="row">
      <input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 2 <span class="explanation" id="answer5" style="color:red"></span></div>

    <div class="row">
      <input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3 <span class="explanation" id="answer6" style="color:red"></span></div>
    &nbsp;
    <div class="row">
      <h3>Question 3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1 <span class="explanation" id="answer7" style="color:red"></span></div>
    <div class="row">
      <input name="con" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 2 <span class="explanation" id="answer8" style="color:green"></span></div>
    <div class="row">
      <input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3 <span class="explanation" id="answer9" style="color:red"></span></div>
    <p>
      <p> <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Check" /> </p>
    </p>
  </form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `div` tag with `style="clear:both;"` before the quizbox  `<div class="quizbox">`

```
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>

 <div class="quizbox">
  content
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you've floated your `.container`s, which means they will try to "float", meaning that content below them will collapse on top of those divs. Try to use clearfix, which is basically adding the following to your `.container`:

```
.container:before,
.container:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
}

.container:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Explanation: this adds a pseudo element as the last element to your floated container, which will take the `clear: both` property. This will make it pull its container down regardless of the floated content on either side.

Comment: Suppose they'd want to expand the site further, adding more content, they'd have to keep remembering to add `clear: both` each time to each new element that appears after a floated container. I think it's easier to just add the clearfix once and be done with it.